# NullPointerException in native java code while performing parallelStream.forEach(..)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jvm, java-8, java-stream

I have the following exception (the stacktrace):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor171.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at com.tradair.tnet.services.trades.TradeService.updateUnrealizedPNL(TradeService.java:173) ~[tnet.jar:5.1.1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

which starts at my `TradeService` class here:

```
    public void updateUnrealizedPNL(Set<Org> orgsToCaluclate, Set<Org> orgsToSendUpdate) {
    orgsToCaluclate.parallelStream().forEach(o -> {
        pnlService.updateMidPrices(o);
        Collection<SystemTradeOrder> allLiveTradesByOrgId = tradesRepository.getAllLiveTradesByOrgId(o.getId());
        updateUnrealizedPNL(o, allLiveTradesByOrgId);
    });

    // more code ....
```

So it looks like the exception is thrown inside java native code while running `forEach(..)` method.
I mean, the `NullPointerException` isn't thrown from my own code - not from my consumer function which appears as the argument in `forEach(..)` method.

I double checked that there is no modification to the `orgsToCaluclate` set when this piece of code runs.

This is the initialization of  `orgsToCaluclate`:

```
        Set<Org> orgsToCaluclate = getMarginOrgs();
        orgsToCaluclate = orgsToCaluclate.stream()
                .filter(org -> !isOrgInCloseout(org.getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Any thoughts?..

Comment: Have you tried checking if the collection is empty, null or anything? And also, avoid using parallelStreams if you haven't got at least ~6000 entries.

Comment: Yes, the set has 11 entries, no null values.
Why do you recommend not to use parallelStream in small cases? I do suspect that perhaps it's something to do with parallelStream, but can't point out exactly the cause.

Comment: Does it not fail with a (plain, serial) stream?

Comment: It doesn't always fall. I.e, it doesn't fall on my machine, and it falls on QA machine, seldom, not always. So by moving it to regular (serial) stream, it doesn't happen, but I still can't identify the problem in parallel stream,

Comment: If it never happens with a serial stream, this tells me that something in your code is not thread-safe. This means it doesn't fail in a single-thread situation - only when running in several threads. You should go through your code and ensure that the data structures you use are all thread-safe or otherwise protected by synchronization or locks.

Comment: parallelStreams get interesting when you have a lot of entries because it creates new threads, etc. Although when you have a few entries, creating threads and all the process is quite heavy and you decrease your performances.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We got used to say that an exception’s stack trace reflects “where it happened”, but that’s an imprecise statement. An exception’s stack trace usually reflects where its instance has been *created*.

When we have code of the form,

```
1   String s=null;
2   s.length();
```

The JRE will create an instance of `NullPointerException` when we try to dereference `null` for invoking the method `length()`, so its stack trace will report line `2`.

However, when we have the following code

```
1   String s=null;
2   if(s == null) {
3       RuntimeException rt=new NullPointerException();
4       throw rt;
5   }
```

The stack trace will not report where the erroneous condition has been detected (line `2`) nor where the exception has been thrown (line `4`) but where the instance has been created, in line `3`.

For most practical cases, these places are close enough to make no significant difference, but here, we have an extraordinary situation.

As [tonakai has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995749/2711488), the `ForkJoinTask` will create a new instance of an already encountered exception via Reflection, as we can see [in its source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#593) when the threads mismatch.

When it succeeds, its stack trace will precisely reflect where the new exception instance has been created, which is in some generated code performing the reflective instance creation. Of course, this successful creation can’t be distinguished from the situation when the JRE creates an exception due to an error condition when executing the same code.

But when we look closer at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#584), we see that the entire reflective creation is enclosed with a

```
584             try {
…
604             } catch (Exception ignore) {
605             }
```

block. So if the operation really failed, no exception was visible. Instead, the code had fallen over to return the original exception. This indicates that the reflective code didn’t fail, but instead we see the successfully, reflectively created `NullPointerException` instance returned by `getThrowableException()` and later on deliberately throw by `ForkJoinTask` to report that there was a `NullPointerException` in another thread during the processing.

But this code initializes the *cause* of the new exception to point to the original one. E.g. the following code:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread main=Thread.currentThread();
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            if(Thread.currentThread()!=main)
                throw new NullPointerException();
        });
    }
}
```

prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:404)
    at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:560)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:9)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

so you are still able to recognize what happened. You just have to pay attention to the *cause*. Since the stack trace in your question doesn’t look like the typical [`Throwable.printStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace--) output, it might be the code which produced this output which ignored the cause property of the exception.

---

As an addendum, we can check what happens if that recreation really fails using a custom exception type:

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main
{
    public static class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
        public CustomException() {
            System.err.println("will deliberately fail");
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        private CustomException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread main=Thread.currentThread();
        IntStream.range(0, 1000).parallel().forEach(i -> {
            if(Thread.currentThread()!=main)
                throw new CustomException("forced failure");
        });
    }
}
```

will print

```
will deliberately fail
Exception in thread "main" Main$CustomException: forced failure
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:18)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.accept(ForEachOps.java:205)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
    at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

showing that the `NullPointerException` thrown during the reflective recreation via the default constructor stays unreported and the original exception from the other thread is thrown directly instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really was very helping one.

Answer (score 4):

looking at the stacktrace it looks like there is an exception happening in your code, and it is trying to get a new instance of that exception but fails to do so because of NullPointerException, can you check your code if any of the code that is called in that foreach throws any exception and make sure 
all constructors of those exceptions are correct

```
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
```

Comment: In that case I would have to get an exception out of my code, not out of the native java code...

Comment: @DimaLih No, tonakai is correct here. Look at the stacktrace (or the source code of ForkJoinTask)

Comment: I've looked there, and understood that doInvoke() method returned with a not-ok exit code. What does it mean? Does it mean there was an exception in my code? If so, I can't see how I didn't get one in my code's stacktrace, and why did I get an exception from java native code. And yet again, the Set I'm foreaching on doesn't have any null values and is not modified anywhere else.

Comment: maybe you can provide some more code and we can take a look, or some of your code is not Thread-safe as mentioned by @RealSkeptic

Comment: @DimmaLih Yes, there was an exception in your forEach() Consumer. That exception doesn't have to be related to the elements in your Set or a modification of your Set. You don't see that exception because a) you don't catch and log it and b) your Consumer code is run in a ForkJoinTask. When the ForkJoinTask determines that it encountered an exception, it tries to report that exception. To provide accurate stack traces, if the exception was not thrown by the current thread a new exception of the same type will be constructed. It's the construction of the new exception that fails with a NPE.

Comment: @DimmaLih `Throwable wx = (Throwable)(noArgCtor.newInstance())` That's line 598 in ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException which fails. `noArgCtor` is a non-null java.lang.reflect.Constructor that represents a public, no-argument constructor of the exception that was thrown by your forEach() Consumer code. Somehow instantiating a new instance of this exception fails with a NPE - this is what you see in the stacktrace.

Comment: @Stefan Zobel: we *do* see the primary exception, at least its type. It’s a `NullPointerException`. The key point is that this answer is right in that there is a reflective recreation of the exception, but it’s misinterpreting the outcome. The recreation *succeeded*. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39018586/2711488)

Comment: @Holger I stand corrected:) Thanks for your elaborate investigation of this puzzle! I actually realized the `catch (Exception ignore)` but assumed that the stacktrace got logged further down the call stack.