# Why a parallelism ForkJoinPool double my exception?

Tags: java, exception, java-8, fork-join

assuming I have the code like as below:

```
Future<Object> executeBy(ExecutorService executor) {
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    });
}
```

there is no problem when using `ForkJoinPool#commonPool`, but when I using a parallelism `ForkJoinPool` it will double the `IllegalStateException`. for example:

```
executeBy(new ForkJoinPool(1)).get(); 
//                              ^--- double the IllegalStateException
```

**Q1**: why the parallelism `ForkJoinPool` double the `Exception` occurs in the `Callable`?

**Q2**: how to avoiding this strange behavior?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38994907/2711488)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Fork/Join pool generally attempts to recreate the exception within the caller’s thread if the exception has been thrown in a worker thread and sets the original exception as its cause. This is what you perceived as “doubling”. When you look closer at the stack traces, you will notice the difference between these two exceptions.

The common pool is not different in that regard. But the common pool allows the caller thread to participate in the work when waiting for the final result. So when you change you code to

```
static Future<Object> executeBy(ExecutorService executor) {
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException(Thread.currentThread().toString());
    });
}
```

you will notice that it often happens that the caller thread is faster in calling `get()` and do work-stealing within that method than a worker thread can pick up the task. In other words, your supplier has been executed within the main/caller thread and in this case, the exception will not be recreated.

This feature can easily disabled by throwing an exception type which has no matching public constructor the F/J could use, like with this neat inner class:

```
static Future<Object> executeBy(ExecutorService executor) {
    return executor.submit(() -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException() {
                @Override
                public String toString() {
                    String s = getClass().getSuperclass().getName();
                    String message = getLocalizedMessage();
                    return message!=null? s+": "+message: s;
                }
            };
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, @Holger. is there a simper way to avoiding this strange behavior? I can think the only way is check it whether a parallelism `ForkJoinPool`  and then wrap the returned `Future`.

Comment: I added one possibility.

Comment: I mean, other than seeing a stack that says IllegalStateException caused by IllegalStateException... what really is the strange behavior? It seems to me this is to properly preserve line numbers and purity of the stack.

Comment: @Holger neat inner class is slick. Something i'm going to keep around in the ole favorites

Comment: @Holger so.. its basically because one thread created the task, some other thread steals it and throws and Exception; thus there are two places where this exception is reported?

Comment: @Eugene: no, as elaborated more detailed in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44705721/2711488), it’s a special feature of F/J to report both stack traces if an exception has been thrown in the worker thread, which is implemented by creating a copy of the exception within the caller thread. The work stealing happens in the other scenario, where the initiating thread submits a task, then immediately calls `get()` and steals the job back from the queue and executes it itself, so no other thread is involved. Then, no exception copying happens.

Answer (score 9):

The `ForkJoinPool` creates `ForkJoinTask` instances to execute your submissions.

`ForkJoinTask` tries to provide an accurate stack trace when exceptions occur. Its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) states

> Rethrown exceptions behave in the same way as regular exceptions, but,
>   when possible, contain stack traces (as displayed for example using
>   `ex.printStackTrace()`) of both the thread that initiated the
>   computation as well as the thread actually encountering the exception;
>   minimally only the latter.

This is [the comment in the `private` implementation of this behavior](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/6be37bafb11a/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.java#l547)

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns a rethrowable exception for the given task, if
>  * available. To provide accurate stack traces, if the exception
>  * was not thrown by the current thread, we try to create a new
>  * exception of the same type as the one thrown, but with the
>  * recorded exception as its cause. If there is no such
>  * constructor, we instead try to use a no-arg constructor,
>  * followed by initCause, to the same effect. If none of these
>  * apply, or any fail due to other exceptions, we return the
>  * recorded exception, which is still correct, although it may
>  * contain a misleading stack trace.
>  *
>  * @return the exception, or null if none
>  */
> private Throwable getThrowableException() {
> ```

In other words, it takes the `IllegalStateException` your code threw, finds a constructor of `IllegalStateException` that receives a `Throwable`, invokes that constructor with the original `IllegalStateException` as its argument, and returns the result (which is then rethrown within a `ExecutionException`).

Your stack trace now also contains the stack trace for the `get` call.

With `ForkJoinPool` as your `ExecutorService`, I don't believe you can avoid it, it's dependent on *if the exception was not thrown by the current thread* and the constructors available in the thrown exception type.

Comment: thanks sir. but I want to avoiding this strange behavior.

Comment: @holi-java Use a different `ExecutorService` implementation or throw an exception from a class that doesn't have a parameterless constructor nor a constructor that has a `Throwable` parameter. Also, you can always unwrap.