# Why does calling CompletableFuture::cancel cause an immediate CancellationException

Tags: java, java-8, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I am trying to call [`cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) on `CompletableFuture`.

It seems from the docs:

> If not already completed, completes this CompletableFuture with a CancellationException. Dependent CompletableFutures that have not already completed will also complete exceptionally, with a CompletionException caused by this CancellationException.

That it should complete them exceptionally which is what I was expecting but instead, it throws and immediate CancellationException.

Here is a sample code

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> false);
f.cancel(true);  // Line 7.
f.join();
```

With a repro : https://www.mycompiler.io/view/2v1ME4u

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.cancel(CompletableFuture.java:2396)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

Line 7 is the `f.cancel(true);` line.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I cut down your sample code to a much simpler example.

Comment: @AndyTurner haha I am grateful for the edit should have though of this myself TBH but alas you beat me to it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't actually throw immediately.

Calling `f.cancel(true)` causes a `CancellationException` to be *created*, capturing the stack trace of the call to `cancel`. So the stack trace (which is printed because it's unhandled) contains the line of the `f.cancel(true);` call.

But that exception isn't actually thrown until [`f.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join()):

> Returns the result value when complete, or throws an (unchecked) exception if completed exceptionally
>
> ...
>
> Throws:
>
> CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled

You can see this by putting in a few more print statements [into your example code](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/0NHIab5):

```
CompletableFuture<?> f = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> false);
f.cancel(true);  // Line 8.
try {
    f.join();
} catch (CancellationException e) {
    System.out.println("CancellationException was thrown at call to f.join()");
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Output:

```
CancellationException was thrown at call to f.join()
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.cancel(CompletableFuture.java:2396)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Comment: Oh man the stack trace really got me though, because it says ` at ... at Main.main(Main.java:40)` which is the line for the cancel call

Comment: @Darius yeah, it's a bit of a stinker. I'd have expected it to be a CancellationException, with the exception from line 40 as the cause.

Comment: Yeah, the subtle differences between “where did the exceptional situation occur”, “where has the exception object been created”, and “where was it thrown” can lead to some confusion, especially with `CompletableFuture`. Like in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38994907/2711488)