# What does `javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError` mean?

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing

Read this [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/FactoryConfigurationError.html) but wasn't clear when the follow exception occurs. Exception thrown `javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError`. Is it that when parallel stream is been used too many threads are been used and the host has ran out of threads?

Have a following code

```
class Foo {
  private Bar bar;
  // trying to limit the TPS agreement. 
  private final RateLimiter LIMITER = RateLimiter.create(10);
  public void fooBar(List<String> ids) {

    ids.parallelStream()
     .forEach(id -> { // Exception thrown in this line
        LIMITER.acquire();
        this.bar.getObject(id)
     }
}
```

```
class Bar {
  public Object getObject(String id) { 
  // calls some API
  }
}
```

Stack trace

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError
....
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.FactoryConfigurationError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:159)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:485)
    at com.foo.local.customAPI.Foo.fooBar(Foo.java:8)
    at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:149)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    ... 123 more
```

Comment: This is not the complete exception. Show the “Caused by” part.

Comment: Have updated the stack trace. The exception isn't thrown always so its tricky to reproduce this issue locally.

Comment: Maybe, I wasn’t clear enough. While the posted `FactoryConfigurationError` is the cause of the `NestedServletException`, it must itself have a cause of type `FactoryConfigurationError`. What you have posted, is an exception created in the initiating thread of the parallel stream operation in response to an exception thrown in one of the worker threads. That original exception should be registered as cause to the posted exception. To identify the actual problem, we need the original exception. The 2 exceptions have been discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38994907/2711488).